# How to find out AirPort Extreme external gateway IP address?

Tags: home-networking, airport-extreme

I am trying to help a friend in trouble, and he needs help locating parameters assigned to AirPort Extreme by router above it. Specifically, he needs to find out Gateway IP address. How can it be discovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the AirPort Utility and open that base station's configuration.